# Attempt to present GADNFullScreenAdViewController on ViewController which is already presenting SecondViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I am implementing Admob Interstitial Admob Ad in my iOS app. I need to show ad between transition from a Second View Controller to a (Main) View Controller. I display Second View Controller as "Present Modally", "Over Current Context". It looks like popup window.

When I return from Second (popup) View Controller (close/hide it), I have an error: Attempt to present GADNFullScreenAdViewController on ViewController which is already presenting SecondViewController.

How to handle this situation in a right way?

```
@IBAction func afterShowingSecond(_ segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let secondViewController = segue.source as? SecondViewController {
        if (secondViewController.someObject != nil) {
            if (interstitial.isReady && interstitialAdIntervalExpired && !doNotShowAds) {
                interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
                return
            }
            // some code
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the function `dismiss(animated:completion:)`

```
if let presentingVC = self.presentingViewController {
    self.dismiss(animated: true) {
        let vc = YourViewController()
        presentingVC.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, just added self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)